# Draw an outline outside the path surface

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the following code to draw shapes (mainly used for rectangles) but the HTML5 drawing functions seem to draw borders with their thickness centered on the lines specified. I would like to have a border outside the surface of the shape and I'm at a loss.

[image]

```
Path.prototype.trace = function(elem, closePath) {
  sd.context.beginPath();
  sd.context.moveTo(this.getStretchedX(0, elem.width), this.getStretchedY(0, elem.height));
  sd.context.lineCap = "square";

  for(var i=1; i<this.points.length; ++i) {
    sd.context.lineTo(this.getStretchedX(i, elem.width), this.getStretchedY(i, elem.height));
  }

  if(closePath) {
    sd.context.lineTo(this.getStretchedX(0, elem.width), this.getStretchedY(0, elem.height));
  }
}
```

getStrechedX and getStretchedY return the coordinates of the nth vertex once the shape is applied to a set element width, height and offset position.

---

Thanks to Ken Fyrstenberg's answer I've got it working for a rectangle, but this solution can sadly not apply to other shapes.

http://jsfiddle.net/0zq9mrch/

[image: failed triangles]

Here I drew two "wide" borders, one subtracting half the lineWidth to every position, another one adding. It doesn't work (as expected) because it's only going to put the thick lines above and to the left in one case, under and to the right in another - not "outside" the shape. You can also see a white area around the slope.

---

I tried working out how I could get the vertices to manually draw the path for the thick border (using `fill()` instead of `stroke()`).

[image: thick triangle with vertices shown]

But it turns out I still end up with the same problem: how to programatically determine if an edge is inside or outside. This would require some trigonometry and a heavy algorithm. For the purpose of my current work, this is too much trouble. I wanted to use this to draw a map of a building. The room walls need to be drawn outside the given dimensions, but I'll stick to standalone sloped walls for now.

Comment: You're just drawing lines, there is no concept of "inside" or "outside" for a line.  I believe you'll just have to deal with this yourself and offset the line by .5 the width of the line in whatever direction you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

You can solve this by drawing two lines:

- First line with line thickness as intended
- Second line contracted with 50% of the outer line width

To contract, add 50% to x and y, subtract line-width (or 2x 50%) from width and height.

## Example

[image: snap]

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
var lineWidth = 20;
var lw50 = lineWidth * 0.5;

// outer line
ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;         // intended line width
ctx.strokeStyle = "#975";          // color for main line
ctx.strokeRect(40, 40, 100, 100);  // full line

// inner line
ctx.lineWidth = 2;                 // inner line width
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";          // color for inner line

ctx.strokeRect(40 + lw50, 40 + lw50, 100 - lineWidth, 100 - lineWidth);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

## Complex shapes

[image: snap complex]

For more complex shapes you will have to calculate the path manually. This is a little bit more complex and perhaps too broad for SO. You have to consider things like tangents, angle at bends, intersections and so forth.

One way to "cheat" is to:

- draw the main line at full thickness to canvas
- then use reuse the path as a clipping mask
- change composite mode to destination-atop
- draw the shape offset in various direction
- restore clipping
- change color and reuse path again for the main line.

The `offset` value below will determine the thickness of the inner line while the `directions` will determine resolution.

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
var lineWidth = 20;
var offset = 0.5;                                   // line "thickness"
var directions = 8;                                 // increase to increase details
var angleStep = 2 * Math.PI / 8;

// shape
ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;                          // intended line width
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";                           // color for inner line
ctx.moveTo(50, 100);                                // some random shape
ctx.lineTo(100, 20);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.lineTo(300, 100);
ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.save()

ctx.clip();                                         // set as clipping mask
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";  // draws "behind" existing drawings

for(var a = 0; a < Math.PI * 2; a += angleStep) {
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, offset * Math.cos(a), offset * Math.sin(a));
  ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0);
}

ctx.restore();                              // removes clipping, comp. mode, transforms

// set new color and redraw same path as previous
ctx.strokeStyle = "#975";                           // color for inner line
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas height=250></canvas>
```

Comment: Actually, I want the opposite (the shape is defined by the black line and then the brown one is added outside), but I get the idea. I'll give a try to see what it gives me with other shapes.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil this will only work with simple/rectangle shapes. If you need more complex shapes then this can help - draw the shape to off-screen canvas, then use a similar approach as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467349/in-a-2d-canvas-is-there-a-way-to-give-a-sprite-an-outline/27127273#27127273

Comment: All hail Ken Fyrstenberg! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

**I'm late to the party, but here's an alternate way to "outside stroke" a complex path.**

It uses a `PathObject` to simplify the process of creating the outside stroke.

The `PathObject` saves all the commands and arguments used to define your complex path.

This PathObject can also replay the commands--and can thereby redefine/redraw the saved path.

The PathObject class is re-usable. You can use it to save any path (simple or complex) that you need to redraw.

Html5 Canvas will soon have its own Path2D object built into the context, but my example below has a cross-browser polyfill that can be used until the Path2D object is implemented.

*An illustration of a cloud with a silver lining applied using an outside stroke.*

[image]

**"Here's how it's done..."**

- Create a `PathObject` that can save all the commands and arguments used to define your complex path. This `PathObject` can also replay the commands--and can thereby redefine the saved path. Html5 Canvas will soon have its own `Path2D` object built into the context, but my example below is a cross-browser polyfill that can be used until the `Path2D` object is implemented.
- Save a complex path using the PathObject.
- Play the path commands on the main canvas and fill/stroke as desired.
- Play the path commands on a temporary in-memory canvas.
- On the temporary canvas:

  - Set a `context.lineWidth` of twice your desired outside stroke width and do the stroke.
  - Set `globalCompositeOperation='destination-out'` and fill. This will cause the inside of the complex path to be cleared and made transparent.
- Draw the temporary canvas onto the main canvas. This causes your existing complex path on the main canvas to get the "outside stroke" from the in-memory canvas.

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
        function log(){console.log.apply(console,arguments);}

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");


// A "class" that remembers (and can replay) all the 
// commands & arguments used to define a context path
var PathObject=( function(){

    // Path-related context methods that don't return a value
    var methods = ['arc','beginPath','bezierCurveTo','clip','closePath',
      'lineTo','moveTo','quadraticCurveTo','rect','restore','rotate',
      'save','scale','setTransform','transform','translate','arcTo'];

    var commands=[];
    var args=[];

    function PathObject(){       
        // add methods plus logging
        for (var i=0;i<methods.length;i++){   
            var m = methods[i];
            this[m] = (function(m){
                return function () {
                    if(m=='beginPath'){
                        commands.length=0;
                        args.length=0;
                    }
                    commands.push(m);
                    args.push(arguments);
                    return(this);
            };}(m));
        }
        
        
    };

    // define/redefine the path by issuing all the saved
    //     path commands to the specified context
    PathObject.prototype.definePath=function(context){
        for(var i=0;i<commands.length;i++){
            context[commands[i]].apply(context, args[i]);            
        }
    }   

    //
    PathObject.prototype.show=function(){
        for(var i=0;i<commands.length;i++){
            log(commands[i],args[i]);
        }
    }

    //
    return(PathObject);
})();




var x=75;
var y=100;
var scale=0.50;

// define a cloud path
var path=new PathObject()
.beginPath()
.save()
.translate(x,y)
.scale(scale,scale)
.moveTo(0, 0)
.bezierCurveTo(-40,  20, -40,  70,  60,  70)
.bezierCurveTo(80,  100, 150, 100, 170,  70)
.bezierCurveTo(250,  70, 250,  40, 220,  20)
.bezierCurveTo(260, -40, 200, -50, 170, -30)         
.bezierCurveTo(150, -75,  80, -60,  80, -30)
.bezierCurveTo(30,  -75, -20, -60,   0,   0)
.restore();


// fill the blue sky on the main canvas
ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// draw the cloud on the main canvas
path.definePath(ctx);
ctx.fillStyle='white';
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle='black';
ctx.lineWidth=2;
ctx.stroke();

// draw the cloud's silver lining on the temp canvas
path.definePath(ctx1);
ctx1.lineWidth=20;
ctx1.strokeStyle='silver';
ctx1.stroke();
ctx1.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';
ctx1.fill();

// draw the silver lining onto the main canvas
ctx.drawImage(canvas1,0,0);
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Main canvas with original white cloud + small black stroke<br>The "outside silver lining" is from the temp canvas</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<h4>Temporary canvas used to create the "outside stroke"</h4>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I'm not going to use this solution simply because it requires me to add yet another buffering canvas to my app for only one shape type, but it's a very clever solution. Bonus points for making the path functions chainable.